# Filtering on tags in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a question about filtering on the Facebook graph API.

Is it a way to filter the results with the Facebook Graph API for `/tags` endpoint?

For example, to filter on `media_type` or with the `timestamp` fields.

I tried to do this, but it does not work:

```
GET {user-id}/tags?fields=media_type,id&filtering=[{field:'media_type',operator:"EQUAL",value:"IMAGE"}]
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here, there is no `tags` edge on user objects as far as I know. But in general, filtering capabilities of the Graph API are rather limited; if the documentation for an endpoint does not explicitly mention any specific filtering possibilities, that usually means there aren't any.

Comment: There is. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/tags

Comment: Okay, so you are talking about Instagram users, not Facebook users. But as I said, if there was any filtering available, the documentation should mention it.